# Query on Web Data Scraping

Tags: screen-scraping, web-scraping

I am trying to get all the data from http://www.nationwide.com/locator/home/index.x?lineOfBusiness=insurance_agent&locatorhome=fromhome&language= every state listed there. Basically the name, address, email, etc.

My problem is:

1. There is no URL parameters for me to iterate through the states from the drop down.

I am willing to iterate through the states manually but then is there any way I can just select on one div and copy content/text from all similar DIVs. I mean you can see there is a  tag there inside which they have whole content. How do I extract the text from all occurrences of text inside the  tag?

I am not particular about any scripting language, Php, perl python or even a simple firefox addon... I just need the result. Any guidance please?

---

My try using web harvest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config charset="ISO-8859-1">
     <!-- sends post request with state name -->
     <http>
        <http method="post" url="http://www.nationwide.com/locator/home/index.x?lineOfBusiness=insurance_agent&locatorhome=fromhome&language=">
        <http-param name="state">AL</http-param>
        <http-param name="searchType">proximity_search</http-param>
        <http-param name="requestSource">home_NI</http-param>
        <http-param name="businessType">NI</http-param>
        <http-param name="language">en</http-param>
        <http-param name="UserAddressCookieAction">createUserAddressCookie</http-param>
    </http>
      <!-- collects content inside address tag -->


</config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use irobotsoft scraper.  Check out demos here:

http://irobotsoft.com/help/

To iterate through the dropdown list, you can follow this thread:

http://irobotsoft.org/bb/YaBB.pl?num=1248753202

Answer (score 0):

I can't load your page, but I can still help hopefuly. You could use a great software:

http://jsoup.org/

For automaticaly scraping this data. However, you will have to write a small Java program. To get the css selectors (thats what you could base your scraping on) you can use Firebug add-on in firefox.

If you don't feel like writing Java code, you could use another amazing tool:

http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/

On their page you can see a lot of examples, even using post methods.

If you need any more help, let me know!

Comment: Sorry for the wrong link . Its http://www.nationwide.com/locator/home/index.x?lineOfBusiness=insurance_agent&locatorhome=fromhome&language= I will go through your sources now and see if it helps me. Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at this example: http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/samples.php?num=4 Since you need a post to get a particular address here. To get the xpath expression you need- inspect with firebug.

Comment: And to see what 'post' do you need- use https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/

Comment: I managed to do the http part of it. I however am stuck at scraping data though. Please see my main post. I have updated it with the web-harvest code.

Comment: If you want the text from all address tags, you can just use XPath like `//address/normalize-space()`